# React native ScrollView drop frames

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using  for a screen that can not use  because the page has multiple components but the screen UI frames dropped to 20fps when trying to scroll.

video for the screen: https://streamable.com/ngqozz

screen code:

```js
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
          {...}
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.supplication}>
           {...}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tsbeeh}>
            {...}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

Comment: This problem caused by something on your screen can you share your code on github?

Comment: @LouaySleman https://gist.github.com/itsosmx/30ebc81ee6cd47e88b01a2707ece8a0e

Comment: I got this error `This secret gist has been disabled.`